# australia post tracking API integration

Tags: c#, asp.net

we are developing an online shopping site and we are using Australia Post as our shipping method. so we are also using a tracking system for Australia Post.

Can anyone tell me how can I integrate Australia post API for tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is documented here: [Delivery Choice technical specifiction](http://auspost.com.au/devcentre/assets/pdfs/delivery-choice-technical-specificationv234.pdf)

It looks like you will need either an API key or a user account with Australia Post in order to access this functionality.

The vast majority of the methods support XML/JSON access, with some using OAuth. There are a number of different approaches you could use to call these methods from within the .NET Framework; `HttpWebRequest` probably being the simplest.

Comment: Link no longer exists. If anyone has the new link, please let me know.

Comment: Try here: https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/shipping-and-tracking/getting-started